# cannot be resolved error

Tags: android, bluetooth

R.java generating but layouts and strings in JAVA file still showing following problem

console....

```
button_scan cannot be resolved or is not a field    DeviceListScan.java 

device_list cannot be resolved or is not a field    DeviceListScan.java 
etc....
```

below is R.java file everything is generated in it but still have problem , that is for all layout and strings im accessing it says cannot be resolved or is not a feild....

r.java file

```
    package com.android.settings.bluetooth;

public final class R {
   public static final class attr {
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int button_scan=0x7f060006;
    public static final int new_devices=0x7f060005;
    public static final int paired_devices=0x7f060003;
    public static final int title_left_text=0x7f060000;
    public static final int title_new_devices=0x7f060004;
    public static final int title_paired_devices=0x7f060002;
    public static final int title_right_text=0x7f060001;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int custom_title=0x7f030000;
    public static final int device_list=0x7f030001;
    public static final int device_name=0x7f030002;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    public static final int bt_not_enabled_leaving=0x7f040003;
    public static final int button_scan=0x7f04000d;
    public static final int discoverable=0x7f040010;
    public static final int insecure_connect=0x7f04000f;
    public static final int none_found=0x7f04000a;
    public static final int none_paired=0x7f040009;
    public static final int not_connected=0x7f040002;
    /**   DeviceListActivity 
     */
    public static final int scanning=0x7f040007;
    /**  Options Menu 
     */
    public static final int secure_connect=0x7f04000e;
    public static final int select_device=0x7f040008;
    /**   BluetoothChat 
     */
    public static final int send=0x7f040001;
    public static final int title_connected_to=0x7f040005;
    public static final int title_connecting=0x7f040004;
    public static final int title_not_connected=0x7f040006;
    public static final int title_other_devices=0x7f04000c;
    public static final int title_paired_devices=0x7f04000b;
}
public static final class style {
    /** 
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

     */
    public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f050000;
    /**  Application theme. 
  All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f050001;
    }
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3259974/1434631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to `Project>Clean` your project & `Project>Build` again.

And also make sure that you have not imported `import android.R;` in your activity.

Answer (score 2):

Try Project -> clean...

If it's not working you might have an error in your XML that isn't shown. Eclipse is weird sometimes.

Also see that you have NOT imported android.R.